# Place markers over map

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map code in javascript, it displays markers based on the latitude and longitude, i have a function within the script through which latitude and longitude are provided to maps.

```
function GetValues() 
    {
        contentstring[0] = "Sector 40 Chandigarh, India";
        regionlocation[0] = "30.739444,76.737981";

        contentstring[1] = "sector 30 chandigarh, India";
        regionlocation[1] = "30.716292,76.787029";
    }
```

What i am trying to do is to fetch values from database and print it in this function, for this i got an array. that is given below. 
from the following code

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($rows);
echo "</pre>";  


Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 25
            [stop] => sec 40d Chandigarh
            [latitude] => 30.7363831
            [longitude] => 76.7309729
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 26
            [stop] => sec 53 Chandigarh
            [latitude] => 30.7163083
            [longitude] => 76.7284448
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 27
           [stop] => sec 60 Chandigarh
            [latitude] => 30.7122544
            [longitude] => 76.7206652
        )

)
```

I tried to loop this array and put the values inside the function but it didn't worked. Can anyone please tell how to do it.

The code that i tried was

```
function GetValues() {
        //contentstring[0] = "Sector 40 Chandigarh, India";
        //regionlocation[0] = "30.739444,76.737981";
        <? 
        for($i=0;$i<count($rows); $i++)
        {?>
            contentstring[<? echo $i; ?>]
        <?}?> 
        = 
        <?foreach($rows as $row4) 
            {
                contentstring[1] = '<? echo $row4['stop']; ?>';
                regionlocation[1] = "<? echo $row4['latitude']; echo ","; echo $row4['longitude']; ?>";
            <?}?>
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use JSON - Get the values from your database and then use `json_encode` to create the json object to use in your javascript function.

```
/* echo the results as a javascript variable */
<script type='text/javascript'>
<?php
    echo "var json=".json_encode( $rows ).";";
?>
</script>

/*
    which would yield something like
*/
<script type='text/javascript'>
var json={
    {"id":"25","stop":"sec 40d Chandigarh","latitude":"30.7363831","longitude":"76.7309729"},
    {"id":"26","stop":"sec 53 Chandigarh","latitude":"30.7163083","longitude":"76.7284448"},
    {"id":"27","stop":"sec 60 Chandigarh","latitude":"30.7122544","longitude":"76.7206652"}
};


function GetValues() {
    if( typeof( json )!='undefined' && typeof( json )=='object' ){
        for( var n in json ){
            var record=json[ n ];
            var contentstring=record['stop'];/* stop is a reserved word in javascript! */
            var regionlocation={ lat:record.latitude, lng:record.longitude };

            /* Add the marker to the map - pseudo code */
            map.addMarker( contentstring, regionlocation );
        }
    }
}

</script>
```